# Storyboard view(iphone 4/5/6) layout effecting collection cell size (programmatically set)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, collectionview

I have setup a story board with a Stack View containing a set of labels each pertaining to a specific section. Beneath this stack of labels runs a collection view, whose item cell size depends on the label directly above it.

i.e the cell size for the first column has a width and height set programmatically to be the width of the label directly above it.

I am accomplishing this through:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {}
```

The problem is, the width of the label that is returning from,

```
label.bounds.width
```

is equal to what the storyboard "View as:" is currently on, and not the simulator running.

i.e

If my storyboard is "View as: iphone 7", and my simulator is running an iphone 5 the width of the label returned is equivalent to what the label width would be in iphone 7. However if the simulator matches the "View as:" in storyboard, everything works perfectly for any device.

All my constraints are set, and the stack of labels and the collection view adjust the size regardless of the any iphone/ipad. Just the cell width seems to be the problem.

I have just started ios development so I may not be very familiar with how these effect one another.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having a similar problem, I fixed this issue in my project through:

```
// collectonViewOutlet is an outlet to the collection view I am working 
// with
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
         collectionViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
```